# Simple select, but reading the result through column name

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am sure this is a very simple question for many people here...

```
$query = "SELECT count(DISTINCT gamecode) as games, sum(psminute) as minutes FROM X2015";
$res = mysql_query($query); 
while ($row =mysql_fetch_row($res)) { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$row[0]."</td><td>".$row['minutes']."</td></tr>";
}
```

I have no results for $row['minutes'], while I do have results when using $row[1] instead. Do you know why? Thank you very much!

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions in PHP are deprecated and shouldn't be used. Please read [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for information on why and what to replace them with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_row`

Read this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

```
$query = "SELECT count(DISTINCT gamecode) as games, sum(psminute) as minutes FROM X2015";
$res = mysql_query($query); 
while ($row =mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['games']."</td><td>".$row['minutes']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

When you use SUM, you also have to do a GROUP BY with every field, except that sum part

```
$query = "SELECT count(DISTINCT gamecode) as games, sum(psminute) as minutes FROM X2015 group by gamecode";
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a simple way to show the query, but you are right.